# Tweet on my behalf through API using twitter-api-sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-api-v2

I'm trying to use [Twitter's official JavaScript/TypeScript SDK](https://github.com/twitterdev/twitter-api-typescript-sdk) to post tweets on my behalf periodically. I've generated an access token and access token secret pair in their develop portal to do this. But [their example code](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tools-and-libraries/sdks/overview#item1) isn't clear how to authenticate like this. I have no problem authenticating with a Bearer token, but that doesn't allow me to tweet from my twitter account.

The following code uses a mechanism to prompt a user for their login, but I don't want this. I want to use my access credentials programmatically.

```
import { Client, auth } from "twitter-api-sdk";
 
// Initialize auth client first
const authClient = new auth.OAuth2User({
 client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID as string,
 client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET as string,
 callback: "YOUR-CALLBACK",
 scopes: ["tweet.read", "users.read", "offline.access"],
});

 // Pass auth credentials to the library client 
 const twitterClient = new Client(authClient);
```

Comment: Using [V1.1 or V2 API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/migrate/twitter-api-endpoint-map) directly, it is much more documented and can use most of the capabilities.